# multiple thin clients and one server?

Tags: thin-client

Is multiple thin clients and one server possible. So for example in a school in a classroom with 30 thin clients while in a back-room there is a single server which all the thin clients can connect and each person can access their own user-space simultaneously.

Roughly what would be required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is definitely possible.  Here's a project that has some good information for you:

http://www.ltsp.org/

Comment: would such a set-up be suitable for call centers?